# Why does including the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" tag break my web-app's offline capability on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, caching, web-applications

I'm trying to create an offline-web app and my `cache.manifest` file is

```
CACHE MANIFEST
http://www.page.com/index.html
http://www.page.com/d3.js
http://www.page.com/list.csv
NETWORK:
*
```

And the beginning of my html is `html manifest="cache.manifest"`

To format the app and make it run full-screen, I included this tag in the header:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

But doing that and running it from the homescreen will result in the app failing, and requesting an internet connection.

If you take that one line out and run it from the homescreen, it will open in safari with the url bar and everything, but the app will run correctly.

I've seen this problem discussed in a couple places such as [here](http://www.offlinewebapp.com/solved-apple-mobile-web-app-capable-manifest-error/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717297/2374028), but never with any working solutions or explanations.

Does anyone know why this is or how to avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">
```

For iOS 7.1, this works as a superior alternative.